# Material UI (MUI) date picker with react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm creating a form which has a date field. I'm using MUI and react-hook-form for validation. I've tried to render the field in two different ways, but when submitting my form I'm not getting the expected value:

**Render 1**

Using a Controller component:

```
const [originalReleaseDate, setOriginalReleaseDate] = useState(null);

<Controller
                                name={"original_release_date"}
                                defaultValue={originalReleaseDate}
                                control={control}
                                render={({field}) =>
                                    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
                                        <DatePicker
                                            label="Original Release Date"
                                            value={originalReleaseDate}
                                            onChange={(newValue) => {
                                                setOriginalReleaseDate(newValue);
                                            }}

                                            renderInput={(params) =>
                                                <TextField
                                                    {...params}
                                                />}
                                        />
                                    </LocalizationProvider>
                            }
                            />
```

when I render the field this way, I'm getting `null` for `original_release_date` after submitting the form.

**Render 2**

Registering the field directly using `{...register("reissue_release_date")}` instead of react-hook-form Controlled component.

```
const [reissueReleaseDate, setReissueReleaseDate] = useState(null);

<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
                                <DatePicker
                                    label="Reissue Release Date"
                                    value={reissueReleaseDate}
                                    onChange={(newValue) => {
                                        setReissueReleaseDate(newValue);
                                    }}

                                    renderInput={(params) =>
                                        <TextField
                                            {...params}
                                            {...register("reissue_release_date")}
                                        />}
                                />
                            </LocalizationProvider>
```

this way is working half way. If I manually type the date then I'm getting its value on submit, BUT if I use the date picker and then submitting the form I get `""`.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 5):

```
InputDate.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string,
  label: PropTypes.string,
};
export default function InputDate({ name, label }) {
  const { control } = useFormContext();
  return (
    <Controller
      name={name}
      control={control}
      render={({ field: { onChange, value }, fieldState: { error } }) => (

        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterMoment} >
          <DesktopDatePicker
            label={label}
            control={control}
            inputFormat="DD-MM-YYYY"
            value={value}
            onChange={(event) => { onChange(event); }}
            renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} error={!!error} helperText={error?.message} />}
          />
        </LocalizationProvider>
      )} />
  )
}
```

Comment: getting error control does not exist on DesktopDatePicker

Answer (score 4):

Just modified the above answer with a bracket.

```js
const [reqDate, setreqDate] = useState(new Date());

<Controller
  name="reqDate"
  defaultValue={reqDate}
  control={control}
  render={
      ({ field: { onChange, ...restField } }) =>
      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
          <DatePicker
              label="Request Date"
              onChange={(event) => {  onChange(event); setreqDate(event); }}
              renderInput={(params) =>
              <TextField
                  {...params}
              />}
              {...restField}
          />
      </LocalizationProvider>
     }
 />
```

Answer (score 3):

In most cases, if you are using `react-hook-form`, you don't need to track form fields with `useState` hook.

Using a `Controller` component is the right way to go. But there is a problem with `onChange` handler in your 1st method.

When you submit form, you are getting default date `null` because `field` is destructed, but it's not passed to `DatePicker`. So, `onChange` prop of `field` is not triggered when date is changed and `react-hook-form` doesn't have new date.

Here's how your render method should be

```
render={({field}) =>
     <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
          <DatePicker
              label="Original Release Date"
              renderInput={(params) =>
              <TextField
                   {...params}
              />}
              {...field}
          />
      </LocalizationProvider>
}
```

If for some reason, you need to update component state then you have to send data to `react-hook-form` and then update local state

```
render={({field: {onChange,...restField}) =>
         <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
              <DatePicker
                  label="Original Release Date"
                  onChange={(event) => {
                                            onChange(event);
                                            setOriginalReleaseDate(event.target.value);
                                        }}
                  renderInput={(params) =>
                  <TextField
                       {...params}
                  />}
                  {...restField}
              />
          </LocalizationProvider>
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `renderInput` prop has been removed in version 6.0 of the Date and Time Pickers.

I removed renderInput attribute and added a slotProps:

```
<Controller
    name="dob"
    control={control}
    defaultValue={null}
    render={({
        field: {onChange, value},
        fieldState: { error }
    }) => (
        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs} adapterLocale="pt-br" >
            <DatePicker 
                label="Data"
                format="DD/MM/YYYY"
                value={value}  
                control={control}
                onChange={event => onChange(event)}
                slotProps={{ textField: { error: !!error, helperText: error?.message  } }}
            />
        </LocalizationProvider>
    )}
/>
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'll extend Leo's answer a bit as that worked pretty well for me too:

What you want to do is assign your form props, my example below includes  a Yup resolver and is specific to a schema called Income Schema:

```
import { SubmitHandler, useForm, FormProvider } from 'react-hook-form';
```

...

```
 const formProps = useForm<IIncomeRecord>({
    mode: 'all',
    reValidateMode: 'onChange',
    resolver: yupResolver(IncomeSchema),
  });
```

We then want to wrap our form with a `FromProvider` we also import from react-hook-forms:

```
  return (
    <FormProvider {...formProps}>
      <form onSubmit={formProps.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Grid container direction="column" justifyContent="center" spacing={1}>
          <IncomeForm incomeToSave={IncomeToSave}  />
          <IncomeFormButtons />
          {error && <Alert severity="error">{error}</Alert>}
        </Grid>
      </form>
    </FormProvider>
  );
};
```

So take not here I'm passing all the `formProps` to the `FormProvider`. And Im using the `handleSubmit` from the `formProps`

Now in my child component called `IncomeForm` I have all my fields including the date picker.

The first thing I want to do here is get access to those `formProps`, and I can do that like this:

```
const { register, control, formState:{errors} } = useFormContext() // retrieve all hook methods
```

Now that we have these all setup we can add our DatePicker (I'm using moment for my `dateAdapter`):

```
<Controller
    control={control}
    name="incomeDate"
    defaultValue={incomeToSave.incomeDate}
    rules={{ required: true }}
    render={({ field, }) => {
      return (
        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterMoment}>
          <DatePicker
            closeOnSelect
            format='DD/MM/YYYY'
            label={dateLabel}
            inputRef={field.ref}
            value={field.value}
            defaultValue={field.value}
            onChange={(date) => {
              field.onChange(date);
            }}
            slotProps={{
              textField: {
               variant: "outlined"
              }
            }}
         />
        </LocalizationProvider>);
    }}
  />
```

I can also have a TextField without the use of the Controller:

```
 <TextField
     type="text"
     label={paidLabel}
     title={paidLabel}
     aria-label={paidLabel}
     variant="outlined"
     defaultValue={incomeToSave.paid}
     InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
     error={errors.paid !== undefined}
     helperText={errors.paid?.message}
     {...register('paid', { required: true, maxLength: 25 })}
        />
```

And that's it!

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't replicate your setup, but my guess is that in the first render the
reference to the 'setOriginalReleaseDate' is lost when being passed through the Controller's render arrow function.

```
...
onChange={(newValue) => {                                                      
   setOriginalReleaseDate(newValue);
}}
...
```

so, try putting the logic in a defined function like:

```
const handleOriginalReleaseDateChange = (newValue) => {
    setOriginalReleaseDate(newValue);
};
```

and change the onChange to call the function.

```
...
onChange={handleOriginalReleaseDateChange}
...
```